# Simple debug breakpoint conditions gives me "Unused equals expression"

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, breakpoints, conditional-breakpoint

[image]

I don't know what is wrong here. It happened before to me also when I tried conditional breakpoints some weeks before. Do I do something wrong or it's Android studio bug ?

Also when I leave this there another error pop up:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok looks like android bug to me or multiple... Conditional breakpoint on field don't work and it works when I do the same thing in function. That warning `Unused equals expression` persist thou.

So what I did to actually make it work was to create temporary init function, placed call to log something and placed breakpoint with the same condition there.

`Unused equals expression` warning is quite confusing to me as well as that conditions don't work on fields at last for me, maybe its related that I am running arctic fox preview on M1 mac ? Don't know maybe its just well known bug..

Also that null pointer can be logical because when compiler first gets there commands is actually still null so maybe I could just write condition as `notes.createPlayCommands().size == 0` and only real Android Studio bug is that warning of `unused equals expression` un debug breakpoint view.